# dovecot: pop and smtp doesn't work

Tags: linux, email, webserver, smtp, pop3

I just follow this [link](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=mail&f=2) to try to configure the dovecot on my CentOS 7 server.
But I always can't connect pop and smtp.

When I execute `ps aux | grep dovecot` at my server, I can just see the result below:

```
root     31229  0.0  0.1  15640  1516 ?        Ss   10:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/dovecot -F
dovecot  31231  0.0  0.1   9308  1016 ?        S    10:16   0:00 dovecot/anvil
root     31232  0.0  0.1   9436  1180 ?        S    10:16   0:00 dovecot/log
root     32255  0.0  0.0 112652   956 pts/0    S+   10:54   0:00 grep --color=auto dovecot
```

It seems that the dovecot doesn't do its job because the port 110 and the port 143 are not listened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided only talks about enabling SASL and ensuring the firewall allows POP and IMAP - it does not actually configure them.

You will probably need to edit dovecot.conf and add / uncomment the appropriate lines with the various services.   For example, my config, which does work with POP and IMAP looks like:

```
auth_default_realm = host.name
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
disable_plaintext_auth = no
listen = *
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
login_greeting = Server ready.

mail_max_userip_connections = 30

# mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
# mail_location = maildir:/path/to/%u
mail_location = maildir:/path/to/%u/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}

service lmtp {

        user=mailuser
        process_min_avail = 5

        inet_listener lmtp {
                address=127.0.0.1
                port = 24
                }

        unix_listener lmtp {
                # mode=666
                }
        }

protocols = imap pop3 sieve lmtp
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-master {
    mode = 0600
    user = mailuser
  }
}
service imap-login {
  chroot = login
  user = dovecot
}
service pop3-login {
  chroot = login
  user = dovecot
}

ssl_ca = </etc/ssl-keys/my-required-PositiveChain.crt
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl-keys/mail.networksavvy.org.crt
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!LOW:!SSLv2:ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
ssl_key = </etc/ssl-keys/my.host.key
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
verbose_ssl = no
protocol imap {
  disable_plaintext_auth = no
  imap_client_workarounds = delay-newmail
  mail_max_userip_connections = 50
}

protocol pop3 {
  disable_plaintext_auth = no
  mail_max_userip_connections = 50
  pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
  ssl_ca = </etc/ssl-keys/my-PositiveChain.crt
  ssl_cert = </etc/ssl-keys/my.host.crt
  ssl_key = </etc/ssl-keys/my.host.key
}

protocol lda {
  auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
  deliver_log_format = msgid=%m: %$
  hostname = my.host.name
  postmaster_address = postmaster
  quota_full_tempfail = yes
  rejection_reason = Your message to <%t> was automatically rejected:%n%r
}
```

Note the "protocol" and "service" lines.